# Как отключить GUI у в Network Manager'e Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, wifi

Я работаю над embedded проектом испльзующим урезаный дистрибутив Ubuntu, все взаимодействие с пользователем должно идти через разрабатываемое приложение. Для подключения по wifi я использую nmcli. При этом Network Manager периодически кидает запрос на подключение к сохраненным wifi сетям через графический интерфейс системы(кажется lxde), и я бы хотел отключить подобные запросы, есть ли способ сделать это не выпиливая network manager полностью?
Скриншот:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: если это встроенная система, то ни о каком x-сервере и речи не может быть, соответственно, просто не ставьте те пакеты, которые вам не нужны.